# React Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am following the serverless-stack.com tutorial. But I am stuck after creating the login button.

I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I don't know what is causing the render so many times. 
I combined my LoaderButton instead of importing to make it simpler.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useFormFields } from "../libs/hooksLib";
import { onError } from "../libs/errorLib";
import "../css/index.css";

const LoaderButton = (
  isLoading,
  className = "",
  disabled = false,
  ...props ) => {
    return(
    <Button
      className={`LoaderButton ${className}`}
      disabled={disabled || isLoading}
      {...props}
    >
      {isLoading && <Glyphicon glyph="refresh" className="spinning" />}
      {props.children}
    </Button>
    )
};

export default function Login() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [fields, handleFieldChange] = useFormFields({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  function validateForm() {
    return fields.email.length > 0 && fields.password.length > 0;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
      console.log(history);
      //history.push("/");
    } catch (e) {
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="Login">
      <form onSubmit={ () => { handleSubmit() } }>
        <FormGroup controlId="email" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            autoFocus
            type="email"
            value={fields.email}
            onChange={ () => { handleFieldChange() } }
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="password" bsSize="large">
          <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="password"
            value={fields.password}
            onChange={ () => { handleFieldChange() } }
          />
        </FormGroup>
          <LoaderButton
            block
            type="submit"
            bsSize="large"
            isLoading={ () => { isLoading() } }
            disabled={() => { !validateForm() }}
          >
            Login
          </LoaderButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

hooksLib.js / useFormFields

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const useFormFields = (initalState) => {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initalState)

  return [
    fields,
    setValues({
      ...fields,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    })
  ]
}

export { useFormFields }
```

Comment: You have some code missing from your example: `userHasAuthenticated` and `handleFieldChange`. Also, could you include `useFormFields`?

Comment: One thing you can try is removing code until your render issue goes away. It might help you narrow down what's causing the problem.

Comment: I find it weird that you are passing a function as the `disabled` prop. Shouldn't that be a boolean, like: `disabled={!validateForm()}`

Comment: @tintef yes, I made those changes cause sometimes this error pops up when you try to pass a function call, so I followed the pattern by using an arrow function. I changed it back.

Comment: @Cully ops! I left that code out cause I was actually doing what you were saying. I'll add it back and add some more code.

Comment: @Cully I added my useFormFields hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom hook should look like this if you want to accept the `event` value:

```
const useFormFields = (initalState) => {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initalState)

  return [
    fields,
    (event) => setValues({
      ...fields,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    })
  ]
}
```

Since that parameter is actually a callback that should occur.

---

Also, your `LoadingButton` implementation needs to change to this:

```
<LoaderButton
  block
  type="submit"
  bsSize="large"
  isLoading={isLoading} // This is a boolean value, not a function
  disabled={() => !validateForm()}
>...</LoaderButton>
```

Comment: amazing! I missed the fact it's a function intaking events, that makes way more sense! Haha I did have it like that but someone in the comments stated it should be the other way. Thanks I'll make my changes and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: You're welcome :)  Glad it helped, it was very difficult to spot at first look, so I don't blame you ;)